# Resizing the .xib (cell) vertically in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I created a .xib (cell) that displays store images and store information.

[image]

Gray is the portion of the image that is not resized and is a UICollectionView.

All stores have different sizes, but in UICollectionView (which displays images) they are displayed as Scale To Fill regardless of size.

I would like the .xib vertical size (UICollectionView) to grow and shrink to fit the vertical size of the image. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with `UICollectionViewCell` you don't really need to change/update the xib height or size directly. More importantly what you need is `CollectionViewFlowLayout` methods.

I think what you need is

```
1. In your xib, you should properly layout your items with `Autolayout`. 
2. Make sure that you set the `collectionview.delegate = self` somewhere based on your need
3. Add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods and return proper values.


 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: `width`, height: `height`)
}
```

The above delegate method should be enough but you may want to use others based on your need.